# Proper setup creation for C# app with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, deployment, setup-project

I need a good advice for proper creation setup of C# app.

I have got a C# application, created via VS 2010 and Entity Framework and a SQL Server database.
For setup I'm using a standard VS Setup Project.

How I can properly include my database into the setup?

Should I run a SQL script after the end of installation or are there other ways?

I have got some problems with db access when user installs my app and I want to avoid it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a Script that create the database? or update it

Comment: in my C# project I'm using a _.mdf file._ And when I install it - I copy a database in _appdata/roaming_ folder. is it right?